# Cannot install npm Fluid Player

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, fluid

I am trying to install Fluid Player in my angular project

By - `npm i fluid-player`

[But Getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA3I1.png)

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Try to [edit] your question and copy-paste it into the question itself in between \`\`\` the code \`\`\`.

Comment: What happens when try to run these commands `npm i fluid-player --legacy-peer-deps or npm i fluid-player --force` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error message says you should try installing `npm i fluid-player --legacy-peer-deps` or `npm i fluid-player --force`

- --legacy-peer-deps: ignore all peerDependencies when installing, in the
  style of npm version 4 through version 6.
- --force: will force npm to fetch remote resources even if a local copy exists on disk.